# XPages Dojo DataStore Get and Cycle Through Return Values

Tags: datagrid, dojo, xpages, datastore

My goal is to grab all the rows in the DataGrid that I display, cycle through each row, grab certain items and values, and update fields in the UI.  Based on what I have read, it is best to grab the datastore and go through that.

The user is editing the Dojo datagrid (editable columns) and clicking a Save button to save the changes (RESTService.save()).  During the Save button process, I would like to cycle through the datastore.

I am using examples from this:
http://xcellerant.net/2013/06/13/dojo-data-grid-21-locking-columns/

This is my REST Service:

```
        <xp:this.resources>
<xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"></xp:dojoModule></xp:this.resources><xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="rsVictimsData">
<xe:this.service>
    <xe:viewJsonService defaultColumns="true"
        viewName="InvoiceMPRVictims">
        <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.get("appConfig").keywords.appDataStore.join("!!");}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
        <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("mprKeysValue");}]]></xe:this.keys>
    </xe:viewJsonService>
</xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

This is the Save button:

```
<xp:button value="Save Changes" id="victimsSaveButton">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[// Save the changes...
try{
rsVictims.save();

var jsonStore;

// Get the datastore...
jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({url: "invoices_page1_doc.xsp/rsVictimsData"});

    // Cycle through the jsonStore...

}
catch (e) {
alert(e);
}
]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

I was hoping to get a few examples on how to cycle through the datastore return.  I see ideas in this reference, but not sure which one to use:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.html

Also, does saving the REST Service (rsVictims.save();) before grabbing the datastore give me the current values?

Thanks!

-------------- EDIT 1/6/2014 ----------------------

I have updated the Save button to use this code:

```
try {
rsVictims.save();

var item;
var itemStore;
var itemName;
var itemValue;

// Get the datastore...
itemStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( {
    url : "invoices_page1_doc.xsp/rsVictimsData"
});

itemName = "month_11";

function failed(error) {
    // Do something with the provided error.
    alert(error);
}

function gotItem(item) {
    if (itemStore.isItem(item)) {
        itemValue = itemStore.getValue(item, itemName);
        alert(itemValue);       
    } else {
        // This should never occur.
        throw new Error("Unable to locate the item with identity [sv]");
    }
}

// Invoke the lookup. This is an async call as it may have to call back to a
// server to get data.
itemStore.fetchItemByIdentity( {
    identity : itemName,
    onItem : gotItem,
    onError : failed
});
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

However, I do not get any return values in the gotItem function and I receive no errors.

I may have missed something -- any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/quickstart/data/usingdatastores.html

Comment: @Tim - thanks for the link -- this is making a lot more sense now.  I updated my original post but seem to not get any return values.  If you have a chance, could you take a look at the code and see if I missed something?  Thanks!